# Exercise Henkin Theory

Tags: logic, incompleteness

I'm doing some excercises from the book "The Incompleteness Phenomenom" from Goldstern and Judah.

I have to do this excercise:

Assume that Γ is a theory satisfying the following:

1. Γ is a Henkin theory.
2. For any two constants c,d, either $\Gamma \vdash c=d$ or $\Gamma \vdash c \neq d$.
3. There are two constants a,b such that $\Gamma \vdash a\neq b$.

We have to prove:

Show that Γ is a complete theory.

They give me a hint: For any sentence $\varphi$, consider the sentence $\exists x[(\varphi \land x=a)\lor (\neg \varphi \land x=b)]$.

I start with this:

As Γ is Henkin, there is a constant c such that $\Gamma \vdash \exists x[(\varphi \land x=a)\lor (\neg \varphi \land x=b)] \to [(\varphi(x/c) \land c=a)\lor (\neg \varphi(x/c) \land c=b)]$.

I'm stuck...
Thank you :)